# Why does JUnit ignore @Category annotations on base classes?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

In my project it happens that I have base classes for some of my test categories. So it would be handy if I could add the annotation `@Category(MyCategory.class)` to the base class to add all the test in all the subclasses to my category at once.

It is actually possible to add this annotation at class level, but JUnit / surefire igores it on base classes. I think this behaviour is inconsistent and confusing.

Is there a reason why JUnit does not support this?

Comment: What version do you use (it should be inherited, see https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/558)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is not only a JUnit problem but also a problem of the Maven Surefire plugin. Using the latest surefire version 2.18 inheritance works like a charm, even with JUnit 4.11.

Comment: @AlexR I didn't have to go for the beta version - still using JUnit 4.11

Answer (score 3):

As it is mentioned by @RC it depends on version of JUnit. Annotation `@Category` is annotated as `@Inherited` since Dec, 5, 2012. The latest official version 4.11 available on maven repository is released at Nov, 2012.

The coming soon version is still in beta: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit

So, if you want this and many other features move to JUnit 4.12, beta-3 on your own risk.